# How to convert normal string to datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have normal strings with more than millions data points from .csv file with format as below:

```
Datetime
22/12/2015  17:00:00
22/12/2015  18:00:00
```

I loaded into pandas and tried to converted into datetime format by using pandas.to_datetime(df['Datetime']). However, the new time series data I got that is not correct. There are some new Datetime produced during converting process. For example, 2016-12-11 23:30:00 that does not contain in original data.

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got the answer as below and my code works now.

Comment: Glad you got it =)

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while that I worked with panda, but in your example you have a different dateformat than in the example lines from csv:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

instead of

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

the to_datetime function takes a parameter "format", this should help if that is the cause.

Comment: Thanks so much. I changed the format as you suggested in csv file before loading into pandas DataFrame and it works well now :)

Comment: @Panda-in-Code You should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the option [`dayfirst=True`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime, dayfirst=True)
```

This:

```
Datetime
22/12/2015  17:00:00
22/12/2015  18:00:00
11/12/2015  23:30:00
```

Gets converted to

```
0   2015-12-22 17:00:00
1   2015-12-22 18:00:00
2   2015-12-11 23:30:00
Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```